# Scrape more than one form from webpage using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are 2 forms in a webpage. I'm trying to scrape all the forms and related attributes of a webpage (http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx) using the following code:

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form_count = 0
for form_list in soup.find_all('form'):
    form_count+=1
    action_value = soup.find('form').get('action')
    method_value = soup.find('form').get('method')
    id_value = soup.find('form').get('id')
    print(form_count, action_value, method_value, id_value)
```

However only the first form of the page gets printed twice. How to scrape both the forms and its attributes?
Note: The form_count variable increments to 2 ( As there are 2 forms in the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `soup.find('form')`, which returns the first form it finds on the page, instead of `form_list`, which returns the current form, while iterating through all of them. Your code should look like

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form_count = 0
for form_list in soup.find_all('form'):
    form_count+=1
    action_value = form_list.get('action')
    method_value = form_list.get('method')
    id_value = form_list.get('id')
    print(form_count, action_value, method_value, id_value)
```